# Bulk change of folder view

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

Hello i have been hand changing one of my drives folder view for around 2-3k folders about 5 or 6 times(lost count) and i was wondering if anybody here can refer me to a program or a cmd command to do this. I did a little research on this, the closest i was able to find was in win 10 file explorer under view and options and view again their is an option to apply to all folders, while this does work it changed all my folders that were in the drive and out, if this is the only way is their a way to restrict to stay in the drive that i want?

Comment: There is no need to change the view one-at-a-time. There are a number of *predefined* folder types, or templates, in Windows, e.g., Documents, Videos. Just specify the template for a folder, and all items and subfolders have the same view. See https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/

Comment: ya but in those individual folders some that i have look better being viewed as tile, or large icons, or medium icons